# Linking values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am making a page for a website where customers of the website that rented/bought printers from the company can fill in the amount of printed documents (**of every printer they own**) in the last period.

Now, I need to translate this to MySQL. The idea is when the customer logs in the webpage it loads an overview with the printers they own, all of them in seperate boxes. 
Those boxes each get an input field for the number they are required to submit.

So to make this work I need to put in a Database that, for example, a customer owns 6 different types of printers.

**MySQL**

```
--Table for Customers--
create table TBL_Pers (
Clientnr        int,
Name            varchar,
Post            char(6),
Cont            char(1),
Contdr          tinyint,
p_p_a           smallmoney)

--Table for Printer--
create table TBL_Printer (
PNr             int,
PBrand          varchar,
PName           varchar,
Serialnr        varchar)
```

The problem I run with is I have no clue how to link those different printers to a person let alone if I have to deal with 200 customers and 15 different kinds of printers the company offers.

So as you could probably tell I'm pretty new with MySQL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an association table to relate the two.

This would look like:

```
create table TBL_Pers_Printer (
    Per_Printer_Id  int auto_increment primary key,
    Clientnr        int references TBL_Person(ClientNr),
    Pnr             int references TBL_Printer(Pnr)
);
```

You might want to include additional information in this table, such as the date the person got the printer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "many-to-many relationship".  You implement it by adding another table:

```
create table TBL_Pers_Printer (
    LnkNr           int,
    ClientNr        int,
    PNr             int,
    foreign key (ClientNr) references TBL_Pers(ClientNr),
    foreign key (PNr) references TBL_Printer(PrinterNr)
);
```

And then insert corresponding pairs of person-printer numbers into it.  Here's [one of a multitude of resources](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx) explaining the concept of many-to-many relationship in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a link table TBL_CustomerPrinter (Clientnr, PNr/ SerialNo) where PNr/SerialNo would be the printer, a foreign key and the clientNr would be the client. 
the table will allow multiple clients like below

```
clientID            PrinterID
1                   1
1                   6
1                   7
2                   8
```

i.e. define a set of rules for link table:

- one client can have multiple printers
- one printer can have multiple clients - here is the question  - is this possible with your schema?

Basically you need a correspondence table between client and printer, and you have to define a set of rules for this.
Hope this helps